# Maps API v3: New InfoWindow, with pixelOffset, w/ data from KML.

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml, infowindow

Hello: I'm making progress on my Google Map (see my previous post: [KML markers missing on Google Maps API v3: What's wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593039/kml-markers-missing-on-google-maps-api-v3-whats-wrong/17594273#17594273)), but I'm now stuck, and hoping for help.

My custom-styled map pulls from a KML file with about 20 Placemarks.

For design reasons, I want my Placemarks to open on the RIGHT side of the anchor, rather than the default top/center. I've tried searching in vain for a simple way to do this; closest I've come is: [Issue with infowindows remaining active when another KML layer is selected - Google Maps API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628175/issue-with-infowindows-remaining-active-when-another-kml-layer-is-selected-goo), which I can't make work for me.

Here is an example of what I'm looking for: http://nationaltreasures.aircanada.com/ (its InfoWindows open to right).

*I think* I need to supress the default InfoWindow, create my own that pulls the KML data, and then specify a pixelOffset to my custom InfoWindow, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Thank you in advance!

```
function initialize() {

var styles = [   ]; // Styles removed to simplify code

var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
    {name: "HEPAC"});

var mapOptions = { 
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.69504, -67.69751),
    panControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
    noClear: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ['map_style', google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP]
    }
    };                

google.maps.visualRefresh = true;  

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);

map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

var opt = { minZoom: 7, maxZoom: 9 }; // Sets minimum & maximum zoom level
map.setOptions(opt);

var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://hepac.ca/wp-content/mapping/wellnessnetworksl.kml?f=3',
    preserveViewport: true,
        });

ctaLayer.setMap(map);        

} 

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

antyrat posted about this with an infoWindow to the right of the marker here:

[Googlemap custom infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364533/googlemap-custom-infowindow)

See the link in the accepted answer.

---

EDIT:  Here's an example.  Obviously you will want to include InfoBox.js on your page to get access to that plugin. I hope this works, I didn't test it, but it might point you in the right direction:

```
function initialize() {

    var styles = [   ]; // Styles removed to simplify code

    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
        {name: "HEPAC"});

    var mapOptions = { 
        zoom: 7,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.69504, -67.69751),
        panControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        noClear: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: ['map_style', google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP]
        }
    };                

    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;  

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);

    map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
    map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

    var opt = { minZoom: 7, maxZoom: 9 }; // Sets minimum & maximum zoom level
    map.setOptions(opt);

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://hepac.ca/wp-content/mapping/wellnessnetworksl.kml?f=3',
        preserveViewport: true,
    });

    ctaLayer.setMap(map);   

    google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
        var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description; // ALTER THIS TO POINT TO THE DATA YOU WANT IN THE INFOBOX
        var infoBox = new InfoBox({content: text, latlng: kmlEvent.position, map: map});
    });     

}
```

Google Maps API says:

> Additionally, a click on a KML feature generates a KmlMouseEvent,
>   which passes the following information:
>       position indicates the latitude/longitude coordinates at which to anchor the InfoWindow for this KML feature. This position is generally
>   the clicked location for polygons, polylines, and GroundOverlays, but
>   the true origin for markers.
>       pixelOffset indicates the offset from the above position to anchor the InfoWindow "tail." For polygonal objects, this offset is typically
>   0,0 but for markers includes the height of the marker.
>       featureData contains a JSON structure of KmlFeatureData.

See this page for more info: [KML Feature Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see he/she has used the InfoBox script, but is manually created a marker -- not pulling from a KML -- so I don't this applies.

Comment: Why would it matter where the data comes from?  Just use the InfoBox script with your KML data.  See edit in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks @SeanKendle. Can you further explain this part ---  
var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description; // ALTER THIS TO POINT TO THE DATA YOU WANT IN THE INFOBOX   ---- 

The data is coming from the KML file, but how do I specify that?

Comment: Thanks @SeanKendle. I understand it now, though something is off with the code because it's crashing the map. Trying now to see how to call the Infobox.

Comment: Code doesn't appear to work, but I bet it's just something small missing. Anyone?

Comment: Did you include the InfoBox.js file before your map code?  Include it right after the main Google maps js file.


http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r49/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to @SeanKendle for pointing me in the right direction. Found more or less what I wanted by adding this into my original code.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    showInContentWindow(kmlEvent.latLng, kmlEvent.featureData.description);
     });

 function showInContentWindow(position, text) {
    var content = "<div>" + text +  "</div>";
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content, 
    position: position,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(300, 0),
     })
 infowindow.open(map);
}
```